# Redirect user by subdomain

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

Using iis I want to redirect clients according to the sub-domain they’re using.

For example I want to give a client the following URL `

> client1.mydomain.com

(the client name should be dynamic and be used as a parameter).

When the client uses this URL I want to redirect him to a domain in the following pattern:

> www.mydomain.com/#client1

Is this the right solution and if so what is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As there were no answers, if someone needs to accomplish the same thing, adding the following rule to your web.config will do it.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite sub domain to folder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www?)(.*)\.mydomain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/#{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```